# appending a div to the body

Tags: javascript, performance

I have a html page and I am trying to append a div to the body, it doesnot matter where the div is attached as long as it is in the body tag. I know that document.getElementById is expensive since it performs a search on DOM tree. Another option I was thinking about was document.body and append the div body. Is there any other option that is better than both of these?

Comment: This is micro-optimisation. I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: You could use `document.write('<div>My div!</div>')`.

Comment: I'm with @Stijn on this one, i really wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: @Pieter — He's worried about the performance of getElementById and you're suggesting jQuery?!

Comment: @Quention I'm sorry, I was reading the question too fast I guess! ;-)

Comment: @Stijn You probably should've added "... until it becomes a problem". Donald Knuth has one for this: "Premature optimisation is the root of all evil"

Answer (score 1):

If you have the DOM Element:

```
document.body.appendChild(divElement);
```

If you don't have the DOM Element, only an string:

```
document.body.innerHTML += "<div>yay, I'm on body!</div>";
```

And, for your knowledge, `document.getElementById` *is not used* to append things in the DOM. It just returns you the DOM element, if it exists, searching by the ID. And it's not expensive - actually, it's the faster way of searching elements!

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I knew that document.getElementById is not used to append things to dom, I meant getting the div using the document.getElementById method and then appendin the div to the value returned.